# Какой видеоплеер использовать?

Tags: delphi, видео

Помогите, пожалуйста. Нужен код простенького видеоплеера, который бы при событии `OnClick` на `Image` воспроизводил бы видеофайл, заранее указанный в коде.

**Добавлено.**

Вы знаете, я сделала вот так:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  MediaPlayer.Display:=Loading; 
  MediaPlayer.FileName := 'C:Documents and SettingsОльгаРабочий столЭлектрон. справочникaWelcome.avi'; 
  MediaPlayer.Open; 
  MediaPlayer.Play; 
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  MediaPlayer.Play;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  MediaPlayer.Stop;
end;
```

`Loading` - это панель.
А как можно сделать, чтоб кроме ави еще какое-нибудь расширение читал?

Comment: Вроде бы TMediaPlayer - это обертка для api windows media player'а и должен воспроизводить все, что может встроенный проигрыватель.

Answer (score 1):

Используй `TMediaPlayer`, вот тут [пример](http://delphidevelop.ru/publ/28-1-0-161).